# ionic 3 validation border not showing on ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic3 to create a login page, with form validation. When I run the application for android and browser platform, validation gets displayed with red color bottom border. but for ios platform it is not showing red colored border at the bottom. what I am missing?

**Refer the screen shot**[image: Screenshot of ios platform- not shwing red border]
[image: secreenshot of android platfor- showing red border]

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/

Comment: Thanks for the comment... I have referred it but not getting success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching through the issues reported on github project, I got the answer, posting here so it will help someone else.

**Reference Link**
[Enable text input highlighting for ios](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6449)

> By-default input highlighting for ios platform is set to `false`. All we need to do is, set it to true (enable it) inside a `theme\variables.scss` as follows

```
$text-input-ios-show-focus-highlight: true;
```

Comment: At the first touch the red border bottom is not displaying but after touching second time the input box is triggering red border bottom . Any suggestions . Android is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can add css classes if the input is invalid and not touched:

```
ion-item.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
       border-bottom: 1px solid map-get($colors, danger) !important;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the following worked for me for iOS:

```css
//-- Validation failed
ion-item.ion-invalid.ion-dirty{
       border-bottom: 2px solid var(--ion-color-danger) !important;
}

//-- Validation passed
ion-item.ion-valid.ion-dirty{
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--ion-color-success) !important;
}
```